# How can I change the ID of an element and then refer to it by its new id?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

I am trying to make it so that when one element is keyed in, another element with a specific class will have its id and value changed.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html><body><table><tr><td>

<input type='text' id="A">
<input type='text' id="B" class='SponsorID'>

</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#A").keyup(function() {
   var ThisValue = $("#A").val();
   $(".SponsorID").val(ThisValue);
   $(".SponsorID").attr("id", ThisValue);
});
```

What works? The value of the element with the class of SponsorID changes.

What doesn't work? The id of the element with the class of SponsorID does NOT change.

I would expect that the id would change.  Why does the ID not change?

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GWzpU/16/

Comment: How do you check, whether id changes or not?

Comment: It works for me, Firefox 9.0.1 on Win7 64-bit

Comment: Agreed, just checked it, and it worked in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as is. Try using google chrome or firebug to inspect the dom.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/GWzpU/17/